# Is there a way in RStudio to change the text color of a #text?

Tags: rstudio, rscript, textcolor

i was wondering if i can change the blue #text of my Rscript to something like a red to stand out better. Is there a way of marking the text and then change it somehow?

Thx 4 the help!

I tried nothing so far because i have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colour scheme of your R studio if you go to:
Tools -> Global options -> Appearance.

There are a selection of colour schemes in here which might appeal. You can also create your own colour theme if you don't like any of these so you should be able to create red text doing this. See [here for more info](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio-theme-creation.html#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20new%20theme,RStudio%20will%20generate%20for%20you).